# How do I check if a mask fully contains another mask in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was just wondering if there was a way of knowing if a mask is fully contained inside another mask in Pygame.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 methods:

1. [`pygame.mask.Mask.count()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.count):

   > Returns the number of set bits in the mask
2. [`pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_area()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_area):

   > Returns the number of overlapping set bits

If you want to test whether `mask1` is completely contained in `mask2`, the number of bits of `mask1` must be equal to the number of overlapping bits:

```py
bits_mask1 = mask1.size()
offset = (rect2.x - rect1.x), (rect2.y - rect1.y)
if bits_mask1 == mask1.overlap_area(mask2, offset):
    print('overlapp')
```